# How to create extension function to display progress bar in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am learning to create extension functions in Kotlin and get success in some. I want to create 2 extension functions 1 for display Progress bar when and where ever I call that function and 2 is for dismiss that progress.

I had created Extension for Toast As below and it is working fine.

```
fun Context.showToast(message: String) {
Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
```

But I don't get idea how to do same wit Progress bar without any system threats.

Anyone having knowledge about this can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could show a progress bar in a dialog. I’m sure there are previous questions about that here or tutorials you could search for. If you want to show one that’s directly in your view layout, that is not really suitable for an extension because it would have to rely on the specific layout being used by the current Activity or Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library for proggres;

```
https://github.com/Kaopiz/KProgressHUD
```

init progress your BaseActivity and extend from childs after you can.

```
class LoadingHelper(context: Context) {
private var progress: KProgressHUD = KProgressHUD.create(context)
    .setStyle(KProgressHUD.Style.SPIN_INDETERMINATE)
    .setLabel(context.getString(R.string.loading))
    .setCancellable(false)
    .setAnimationSpeed(2)
    .setDimAmount(0.5f)


fun showDialog() {
    if (!progress.isShowing) progress.show()
}

fun hideDialog() {
    if (progress.isShowing) progress.dismiss()
}

companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var instance: LoadingHelper? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
        instance ?: LoadingHelper(context).also { instance = it }
    }
}
```

}

```
 @AndroidEntryPoint
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var loadingHelper: LoadingHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        loadingHelper = LoadingHelper.getInstance(this)
    }


    fun showLoading() {
        loadingHelper.showDialog()
    }

    fun hideLoading() {
        loadingHelper.hideDialog()
    }
}
```